# Set UIButton image from java script function call

Tags: objective-c, cordova

I am working on PhoneGap. I need to set image on UIButton when javaScript functio call.

to call objective c 'Myfunction' i used this code--

```
PhoneGap.exec("MyClass.Myfunction", types);
```

and able to call objective c method and set the image on help button using--

```
MainViewController * _mainViewController=[[MainViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
[_mainViewController.help setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

but get null object.

can any one help me..?

Comment: So after a js function call you would like to get called an Obj C method, which sets up the MainViewController's background to "back.png"?

Comment: Is the button you want to alter already on the screen?  What you are doing here is creating a new view controller.  Its content won't be loaded unless it is displayed.

Comment: Sorry for mistake..yes button is already on scree. PhoneGap.exec function call a plugin class(MyClass) method(MyFunction) and from this method i need to set the image on "help" button of MainViewController class. But image is not set.

Comment: To change a button that is on the screen, you must access a view controller that is on the screen.  When you call `[[MainViewController alloc] init...`, you create a new view controller.  _Nothing_ you do to this view controller will affect the view controller that is already visible.  You need to get a reference to the view controller that _already exists_.  If `MyClass` is a PhoneGap Plugin, it may be able to access the property `self.appViewController`.  If this makes no sense, please mention what class `MyClass` inherits from.

Answer (score 1):

`MainViewController * _mainViewController=[[MainViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];`

using this you are creating new object, so due to this it can't able to set image on button.

you can set the image on button by calling `PhoneGap.exec`.